# Validate Form and send unvalidated form inputs with angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a question concerning angularJS.

I want to validate a form. If there is an error, I want do an action in order to process the data further. I.e. users has not filled all fields, but I want send the inputs nevertheless.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the `$valid` attribute of the form inside your controller.

> ```
> <form name="newFeed">
>   URL: <input size="80" name="url" ng-model="newFeed.url" type="url" required>
>   <button ng-click="addFeed(newFeed)">Add Feed</button>
> </form>
> ```
>
> In a controller, a bound value can be interrogated for the validation status by checking the > `$valid` property.
>
> ```
> $scope.addFeed = function(feed) {
>   if (feed.$valid) {
>     // Copy this feed instance and reset the URL in the form
>     $scope.feeds.push(feed);
>     $scope.newFeed.url = {};
>   }
> };
> ```
>
> (as taken from [here](http://dailyjs.com/2013/06/06/angularjs-7/)).

You check the `$valid` attribute every time you call `addFeed` by pressing the submit button.